# Test data to test form input fields?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, test-data

I am testing web based user profiles forms which have multiple fields like input box, radio buttons, checkboxes, combo-boxes, alphanumeric fields etc.

what are some good tests that I can run to find issues. How can I try to break the form fields and save/submit functionality?

Comment: [This link](https://onecore.net/sample-test-cases-for-text-field.htm) contains all the information which you need.

Comment: i have doubt what is the name of testing done for login form or search bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These blog](https://strazzere.blogspot.com/search/label/Test%20Data) might help:

Lots of posts there about creating test data, along with copy-and-paste samples.

Comment: This link is not valid as expired.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal - updated.

Answer (score 12):

**TextBox:**

1. Verify name is mandatory or not
2. Enter the value as  blank spaces on mandatory fields and click on Save button
3. Enter the value as Special Character & Numbers on mandatory field and click on Save button (a. 12345, b. /*--+-, 
   c. 12354/*--+-)
4. Check Data type(s) for required field
5. Enter value as "a to Z" and check the character length and click on Save button
6. Check tab validation is working or not
7. Check mouse hover functionality
8. Check spelling and Grammar in Confirmation message

**Radio Button**

9. Check the CSS style, size & color of the radio button is as per the specification.
10. Check if the multiple radio button on the form get select or not.
11. Click on ‘Yes’ or No radio button control and hit submit to see if it redirects to the specific page.
12. Select "YES" option and click on save button
13. Select "No" option and click on save button
14. Select “Yes” option and double click on Next button
15. Without selecting any option click on Next button (If nothing is selected by default)

**Combo box**
**For Country, State & City**

16. Click on the State/County/Region Drop down menu
17. Clicking on the State/County/Region Drop down
18. Check Cascading lookup is working or not
19. Verify the state drop down button if it has all valid states in list
20. Select another state and check city list and make sure list has changed

Answer (score 5):

1. Text field - special characters, numbers, alphanumeric values, negative values, decimal values, blank values, greater than max characters, acceptable ranges, links, html code
2. Text boxes - try adding links, html codes
3. Email address - invalid format, wrong email address
4. Url fields - invalid format, wrong url
5. Credit card - invalid credit card, expired, insufficient balance,
6. Date/Time field - invalid date/time format, older/present/past dates, past/present/future time
7. Radio/Checkbox - Select, unselect, check if any conditional data is displayed based on selection
8. Select/Multi select field - check if any conditional data is displayed based on selection, selection in one drop-down to dynamically populate another drop-down
9. Save form with all blank fields
10. Save form with blank/unselected required fields
11. Save form with invalid values
12. Navigate forward, backward, refresh
13. Check for any help texts
14. Check for error messages
15. Check if there are any Reset or Clear buttons
16. Check if pressing any keys has any any effect like Esc
17. Check you can submit form with all permissible values and verify all data
18. Check end to end functionality, if you can login and perform required actions after creating user profile
19. Check overall format and spellings of the form
20. Try different language
21. Copy paste, drag drop
22. Uploading or downloading files

Comment: By links in text field , do you mean by pasting the URL or something else?

Comment: yes url and after saving the data check if the links are working

Comment: thanks...for example I put a url:- "http://www.urlintextfiled.com/test.index......." in a text field, then I save it. It saves perfectly in my application, even in the database. the link I entered was working correctly. how do I know if its a bug?

Comment: sometimes the url is not clickable after saving ...

Answer (score 5):

Radio Button

- All options are displayed
- All options are enabled
- Multiple selection is not allowed.
- If multiple selection is allowed, check if you are able to achieve it.
- If radio button is a necessary field, check if not selecting it raises an error message
- If any event is associated with radio button, check if that's happening correctly.
- Click on radio button and check if it is enabled (in case using WebDriver)

Check Box

- Same check as of radio button is applicable on checkboxes too.

Combo Box

- All the neccessary options are available
- Check for the default option
- Multiple selection is not allowed
- If multiple selection is allowed, check if you are able to achieve it.
- Check if you are able to type a correct selection option in combo box and the option comes up for selection.
- Type an invalid selection option and check the behavior as per expectations.
- If scrolling option is available in combo box, test it.

Aphanumeric Fields and Text Box : This [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9441/what-are-some-invalid-data-inputs-that-will-break-a-text-box) has a comprehensive list of options

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to test for reflective xss and stored xss vulnerabilities that expose sensitive data via UI. This is where most of the developers failed to implement for security standards.

You can look at the big list of naughty strings (yes, they name it as naughty) :) here on the [github](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings):

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the minimum and maximum character length checks.
Minimum - empty text box
Maximum - use [Lipsum text](http://www.lipsum.com/feed/html)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look at is any potential dependencies between the form inputs.

For example, you might have a promotion or coupon in your website. You have a web app which lets you set the expiry time (just time and not date) of a coupon & time zone of the place where you want to show the coupon. One bug could be that when you change the time zone, the expiry time might get changed to that time zone, automatically. I have seen such a bug in an actual application. It was not an intended feature, but a bug. I am not sure, but I suspect that the bug was due to bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

**Check input validation**- separately for each field and then finally together as a single transaction.

Input Validation:(few pointers in order)

-**Check input type**(char/Numbers)

-**Check min & max value range** where applicable(like name should be 15 char)
-Special Characters what allowed

-**Dependency between Fields**(Ex.Cannot select City without selecting country)

These are just a few pointers from the top of my head, not the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Test cases creation is done in every software testing company for this type of scenario. Below are few cases :

**TextBox:**

1. Verify mandatory fields by providing values and leaving it blank.
2. Verify non-mandatory fields
3. Verify the maximum and minimum character limit
4. Verify XSS validation to handle javascript scenarios
5. Enter the value as blank spaces on mandatory fields and click on Save button
6. Enter the value as Special Character & Numbers on the mandatory field and click on Save button
7. Enter the value as "a to Z" and click on Save button
8. Check tab validation is working or not
9. Check spelling and Grammar in the Confirmation message

**Radio Button**

1. Check if the multiple radio button on the form get select or not.
2. Select "YES" option and click on save button to see if it redirects to the specific page.
3. Select "No" option and click on save button to see if it redirects to the specific page.
4. Without selecting any option click on save button

**Combo boxes**

1. Select any option say country from main dropdown and observe that user is able to select the provinces of the selected country in next dropdown.
2. Verify that list shown in combo box is as per the selection.
3. Select another state and check city list and make sure list has changed

**Alphanumeric field**

1. Ensure that the field does not accept blank data.
2. Ensure that the lower value and higher value specified for the field are handled correctly.
3. Ensure that the field does not accept special characters or symbols.
4. Ensure that the field accepts only valid characters.
5. Ensure that space/blank entry in the first position of the numeric field is reported as an error.
6. Ensure that fields with a blank in the last position are reported as erroneous.