# Security Standards Compliance testing library with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, security-testing

I've been using Selenium for awhile and I know many testers have compiled lists of standard security compliance types of tests to perform, [like are listed here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9441/what-are-some-invalid-data-inputs-that-will-break-a-text-box)

These fall into a list of tests that are performed on every web site for basic security compliance, a short list here:

- Form Fields: Visible and Hidden

  - Escape codes
  - SQL Injections
  - Non-ascii, Unicode vs UTF-8
- URLs

  - Query String Manipulations

*etc.*

**Question:** Since these tests are commonly repeated and fairly generic, has anyone compiled a list of Tests created with Selenium that target these well known security compliance related issues?

Some granular extensions based on common security compliance checks like this:

```
public static class WebDriverComplianceExtensions
{
    public static void InputOneSixty(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        var input = driver.WaitUntil(d => d.FindElement(by));
        input.SendKeys("&#160;");
    }
}
```

And hopefully some sort of intelligent extensions like:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
// some page navigation...
Assert.IsTrue(driver.PerformComplianceCheck(By.Id("FirstNameInputBox")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is not an ideal tool for this kind of testing.  There are existing tools, which will be better suited to the task - Opening a browser, rendering the page and all the associated overhead is wasteful when conducting security testing!

I suggest [Burp suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) or [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project), depending on your full set of use cases and available budget.